# C - Two dimensional matrix, add in a shape of two symmetrical up-down triangles (almost like X)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

The objective: Add only the pieces of the matrix that are part of a full X (upper and lower triangle).

```
1 1 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
```

Like this, middle one should add only once.
I can't add the lower triangle properly. Help much appreciated :)

```
void write(int niz[20][20], int n){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &niz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void x(int niz[20][20], int n){
    //Upper triangle
    int i, j, pr=n, suma=0;
    for(i=0; i<n/2 + n%2; i++,pr--){
        for(j=i; j<pr; j++){
            suma += niz[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",suma);

    //Lower triangle
    pr = n;
    for(i=n; i>n/2 + n%2; i--,pr--){
        printf("%d",pr);
        for(j=n-i; j<pr; j++){
            printf("\n%d", niz[i][j]);
            suma += niz[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%d", suma); 
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Matrix dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Numbers in the matrix: \n");
    int niz[n][n];

    write(niz, n);
    x(niz, n);
}
```

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here are some examples, if the input is:
`
1 1 1 
1 1 1
1 1 1
`
the output would be 7, because of the pattern i described above.
Hope i cleared it up.

Comment: Nope, I purposefully put them as 1. They should be added too.

Comment: So you want to fill the diagonals with `1` and then fill between the diagonals above and below `rows / 2` -- right?

Comment: Yeah, that's about it.

Comment: _"I can't add the lower triangle properly"_ is not a problem description. What, precisely, happened instead of what you wanted to happen?

Comment: Yes - providing several matrix input examples along with what you are getting and what you expect would be most helpful.

Comment: You said X, but you're also counting the middle values on the top and bottom in your example, and you also wrote "triangle", which suggests a more hourglass-like figure. That also makes me wonder about rows 2 and 4 of a 5x5 matrix (assuming rows are numbered 1..5): are they `01110` or can there be holes like `01010`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing separate functions for each lower, upper & diagonals you can do all together with little tricks, but it works only if `row == column` and thats's what you want I think.

```
int main() {
        /* it can be anything like a[3][3] or a[7][7] and elements can 
            be all one or all 2 or any number */
        int arr[5][5] = { {1,1,1,1,1},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
                {1,1,1,1,1} };
        int row = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        int col = sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]);
        int sum = 0;
        for(int index = 0; index < row; index++) {
                for(int sub_index = 0; sub_index < col; sub_index++) {
                        if(index == 0 || (index == row-1) || sub_index == row/2)
                                sum = sum + arr[index][sub_index];
                }
        }
        printf("sum = %d \n",sum);
        return 0;
}
```

Its fine if it helps you otherwise write your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mismatches between the declarations and types of the arguments passed to OP's function. While in `main` they declare a variable length array, named `niz`:

```
int n;
// ...
int niz[n][n];
```

The posted signature of both `write` and `x` requires an `int niz(*)[20]`. It should be changed to:

```
void write(int n, int niz[n][n]);
//    this ^^^ may be a size_t, just remember to write it before the array
```

About the pattern you have to follow for the sum, I can't say to fully understand your requirement, but if I'm not completely wrong, it could be done this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_matrix(int n, int niz[n][n])
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &niz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

// Separate the calculation from the printing
int hourglass_sum(int n, int niz[n][n])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //Upper triangle
    for(int k = n; i < k; ++i, --k) {
        for(int j = i; j < k; ++j) {
            sum += niz[i][j];
        }
    }

    //Lower triangle
    for(int k = i + 1; i < n; ++i, ++k) {
        for(int j = n - i - 1; j < k; ++j) {
            sum += niz[i][j];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Matrix dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int niz[n][n];

    read_matrix(n, niz);
    printf("\nSum: %d", hourglass_sum(n, niz)); 
}
```